# Using a for loop to generate nested conditions in query

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I have a form with check boxes and I would like to create a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'name' AND (option = 'check1' OR option = 'check2' OR option = 'check3')
```

The nested conditions will depend on what checkboxes the user selected.

The only way I know or can find examples on how to do nested conditions look like:

```
$select->where->nest
    ->equalTo('option', 'check1')
    ->or
    ->equalTo('option', 'check2')
    ->or
    ->equalTo('option', 'check3')
    ->unnest();
```

But this would only work with a static number of equalTo's inside the nest, when my case would have a variable amount.
I would like to do something like this (where $filters is an array of checkbox values selected by user):

```
$select->where->StartNest();
foreach($filters['check'] as $check){
    $select->where->like('option', '%'.$check.'%');
    $select->where->or;
}
$select->where->StopNest();
```

Is anything like this possible?  Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thank you very much for looking at the problem!

**EDIT:**

Here is how I ended up doing it.  Seems a little hacky, but it is doing the job for now:

```
$strLiteral = '';
foreach($filters['check'] as $check){
    $strLiteral .= "options LIKE '%$check%' OR ";
}
$strLiteral = substr($strLiteral, 0, -4);  //remove the final ' OR' from string
$select->where->nest
    ->literal($strLiteral)
    ->unnest;
```

Comment: Something like `foreach ... { $select->orWhere($expr->equalTo('a', 'b'));}` should work can't tell you the exact syntax, but generally that should be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  My issue is that the multiple orWhere's need to be nested.  Unless I'm missing something, that would just result in `WHERE name = 'name' AND option = 'check1' OR option = 'check2'` but I'm looking for `WHERE name = 'name' AND (option = 'check1' OR option = 'check2')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it.  Seems a little hacky, but it is doing the job for now:

```
$strLiteral = '';
foreach($filters['check'] as $check){
    $strLiteral .= "options LIKE '%$check%' OR ";
}
$strLiteral = substr($strLiteral, 0, -4);  //remove the final ' OR' from string
$select->where->nest
    ->literal($strLiteral)
    ->unnest;
```

If anyone knows a better way to accomplish this, let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
$p = new Predicate();
foreach($filters['check'] as $check) {
    $p->OR->like('option', '%'.$check.'%');
}
$select->where->addPredicates($p);
```